# Python Pandas to_dict function

Tags: python, pandas

I’m trying to create a dictionary, but can’t get it to work the way I intend.  I feel like I’m so close.  I a df of yelp data:

```
import pandas as pd
file_rev = 'blah.csv'

reviews=pd.read_csv(file_rev, sep=',',header=0, nrows=10000)

cols = ['user_id', 'business_id', 'stars']
cat_rev = reviews[cols]

print cat_rev
```

df:

```
                   user_id             business_id  stars
0   Xqd0DzHaiyRqVH3WRG7hzg  vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA      5
1   H1kH6QZV7Le4zqTRNxoZow  vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA      2
2   zvJCcrpm2yOZrxKffwGQLA  vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA      4
3   KBLW4wJA_fwoWmMhiHRVOA  vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA      4
4   zvJCcrpm2yOZrxKffwGQLA  vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA      4
5   Qrs3EICADUKNFoUq2iHStA  vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA      1
6   jE5xVugujSaskAoh2DRx3Q  vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA      5
7   QnhQ8G51XbUpVEyWY2Km-A  vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA      5
8   tAB7GJpUuaKF4W-3P0d95A  vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA      1
9   GP-h9colXgkT79BW7aDJeg  vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA      5
10  uK8tzraOp4M5u3uYrqIBXg  UsFtqoBl7naz8AVUBZMjQQ      5
```

I want to be able to create this as a dictionary that looks like:

```
abc = {user1 : {business1:star_rating, business2:star_rating…, 
                businessN:star_rating}, 
       user2: {} … }
```

Then to access I would just: 
`abc[user1]` would give me all the places and stars that user1 reviewed.
`abc[user1][place1]` would give just corresponding star rating.

I’ve tried the `to_dict` panda function.  I tried to `groupby` first, then `dict(list(groupby()))`, and nothing seems to convert it to how I want.

Also nope, but almost:

```
ddd = cat_rev.set_index('user_id').to_dict(outtype='list')
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use groupby and a dict-comprehension:

```
{user_id: pd.Series(grp['stars'].values, index=grp['business_id']).to_dict() 
 for user_id, grp in df.groupby(['user_id'])}
```

yields

```
{'GP-h9colXgkT79BW7aDJeg': {'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA': 5},
 'H1kH6QZV7Le4zqTRNxoZow': {'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA': 2},
 'KBLW4wJA_fwoWmMhiHRVOA': {'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA': 4},
 'QnhQ8G51XbUpVEyWY2Km-A': {'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA': 5},
 'Qrs3EICADUKNFoUq2iHStA': {'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA': 1},
 'Xqd0DzHaiyRqVH3WRG7hzg': {'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA': 5},
 'jE5xVugujSaskAoh2DRx3Q': {'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA': 5},
 'tAB7GJpUuaKF4W-3P0d95A': {'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA': 1},
 'uK8tzraOp4M5u3uYrqIBXg': {'UsFtqoBl7naz8AVUBZMjQQ': 5},
 'zvJCcrpm2yOZrxKffwGQLA': {'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA': 4}}
```

Comment: The answer by @ZJS below is cleaner, IMHO.

Comment: @AmiTavory: The OP's desired output implies more than one row can have the same UserID. This answer is more complicated because it handles that case.

Answer (score 2):

you could also just zip up the values with the index...

```
d = {k:v for k,v in  zip(df.index,df.to_dict('records'))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    return dd.set_index("business_id").stars.to_dict()

df1.groupby('user_id').apply(function1).to_dict()
```

output:

```
{'GP-h9colXgkT79BW7aDJeg': {'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA': 5},
 'H1kH6QZV7Le4zqTRNxoZow': {'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA': 2},
 'KBLW4wJA_fwoWmMhiHRVOA': {'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA': 4},
 'QnhQ8G51XbUpVEyWY2Km-A': {'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA': 5},
 'Qrs3EICADUKNFoUq2iHStA': {'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA': 1},
 'Xqd0DzHaiyRqVH3WRG7hzg': {'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA': 5},
 'jE5xVugujSaskAoh2DRx3Q': {'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA': 5},
 'tAB7GJpUuaKF4W-3P0d95A': {'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA': 1},
 'uK8tzraOp4M5u3uYrqIBXg': {'UsFtqoBl7naz8AVUBZMjQQ': 5},
 'zvJCcrpm2yOZrxKffwGQLA': {'vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA': 4}}
```